# There are no inside faces after solidifying my shape

Tags: solidify-modifier

When I create a hollow cylinder and the solidify it, and then in edit mode there are no faces, vertices, and edges inside the cylinder, only outside faces are showed.
[image: As you can see, there are no vertices, faces or edges inside]

Comment: That's correct.  That's how solidify works.  The faces it adds are only generated and not actually present.  If you want to make them present you have to click apply on the solidify modifier.  But once you've done that you can't adjust the thickness anymore.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks Sir, I really appreciate your answer. And it worked !!!